# Android: unable to create a directory in default pictures folder

Tags: android, mkdirs

This is the code i am using to create a folder in the default pictures folder:

```
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, "/images");
if (!imagesFolder.exists()) {
Log.d("if imagesFolder exists - 1", "False");
imagesFolder.mkdirs();
} else {
Log.d("if imagesFolder exists - 1", "True");
}
if (!imagesFolder.exists()) {
Log.d("if imagesFolder exists - 2", "False");
imagesFolder.mkdirs();
} else {
Log.d("if imagesFolder exists - 2", "True");
}
```

in log i am getting:

```
False

False
```

for the 1st time the directory is not present, hence `False` but then immediately i am creating it using `mkdirs()`, hence i expect the 2nd log to be `True` but even that is `False` and my application crashed because of `NullPointerException` in the later part of the code

Please help

Thank You

Comment: post the log cat error message of your NPE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` the wrong way. It's just a `String` constant like  `"Pictures"` but not a path. You need to get the path via [`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(string)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29)

```
File pictureFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
        );
File imagesFolder = new File(pictureFolder, "images");
// etc
```

Comment: @zapi 1 problem here is when i am saving the images in this folder, the size of the images are 30-50 K.B(I am not compressing) where as the size of normal images (taken from camera from home screen) are 2-3 M.B sized. Do you have any idea why it is so?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc You probably save images with a lower resolution, scaled down somewhere. Has definitely nothing to do with the place you safe the images.

Comment: Scaling i am definitely not doing anywhere in my code. But i am using this: "bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bao);" But a PNG is lossless format right? moreover i am using 100 as the quality. Are there any other things to look into?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc whatever you save there has less "image information" ([Entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) if you like it abstract) than the camera images. Either smaller in dimensions or in image content (less details, colors, etc). Yes, PNG is lossless but can use compression. I still think your images have smaller dimensions, than the several megapixel ones from the camer.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a folder at first you need to add permission at **AndroidMinifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Now call following method to create a new folder with in which Directory you want to create your folder(this name should exist in Environment. list) and your folder name.

```
File outputDirectory = GetPhotoDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, "YourFolder");
```

Generate your folder by this method

```
public static File GetDirectory(String inWhichFolder, String yourFolderName ) {
    File outputDirectory = null;

    String externalStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (externalStorageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

        File pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(inWhichFolder);

        outputDirectory = new File(pictureDirectory, yourFolderName);
        if (!outputDirectory.exists()) {
            if (!outputDirectory.mkdirs()) {
                Log.e(LogHelper.LogTag, "Failed to create directory: " + outputDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
                outputDirectory = null;
            }
        }
    }
    return outputDirectory;
}
```

If you want to create a file under your newly created folder then you can use below code

```
public static Uri GenerateTimeStampPhotoFileUri(File outputDirectory, String fileName){
    Uri photoFileUri = null;

    if(outputDirectory!=null) {
        File photoFile = new File(outputDirectory, fileName);
        photoFileUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
    }
    return photoFileUri;
}
```

Call to create a file after creating the folder with File Directory. It will return your file **Uri**

```
Uri fileUri = GenerateTimeStampPhotoFileUri(outputDirectory, fileName);
```