# Why can i not make a directory inside Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES?

Tags: android, external, mkdir

This is my code

```
File selfieLocation = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
               "Daily Selfies");
boolean isDirectory = false;
if(!selfieLocation.isDirectory()) {
        //Creates directory named by this file
        selfieLocation.mkdir();
        isDirectory = selfieLocation.isDirectory();
 }
 //array of strings 
 for(String selfiePath: selfieLocation.list()) {
        selfies.add(selfiePath);
 }
```

Basically what I am trying to do is create my own customizable directory inside of the standard directory in which to place pictures that are available to the user.

I looked at related threads and saw this one, [Android: unable to create a directory in default pictures folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598567/android-unable-to-create-a-directory-in-default-pictures-folder). However I made sure that I had a call to getExternal...., and not just have Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES as a parameter. 
I also looked on here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal and saw that I had the right method call/format to create a customizable folder in external memory. The docs example was

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
if (!file.mkdirs()) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
}
```

I stepped through my code and saw that the local variable isDirectory stayed at false even after the call to selfieLocation.mkdir(). Does anyone know why this directory cannot be created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to create directory with `File#mkdirs()`, not `File#mkdir()`. The latter assumes that all parent directories are already in place, so it won't create directory if any of its parents don't exist.
Also, take a look at your permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`. You need the following permissions in order to read/write the content on external storage:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

`android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` isn't required for now, but [it will be](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) in the future releases of Android.

Comment: the permission isn't the issue because I have that and didn't get a security exception. mkdirs didn't work either. The parent does exist in this case (getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)

Comment: By the way, can you give this question a up vote if you think its a good question? I am in danger of a question ban so I try to make sure that I ask good questions with research from now on.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your error and everything works just fine on the emulator. The issue has to be somewhere else.
I give an upvote whenever I see a question that may be interesting to me. That's good question, with research effort, but it isn't intersting from my point of view.

Comment: Yeah the issue was that my phone's external media isn't even mounted when i plug it into usb of computer. That's frustrating